# Adding an offset to a memory address

Tags: masm, x86-16, emu8086

I have some code like so (emu8086)

```
data segment
    str1 db "hello"
    len dw 4h
data ends

code segment
    ...
    ...
    mov si, offset str1
    lea di, [si + len]
code ends
```

I would expect this to make `di` point to the address of DS:0004, however the actual instruction generated is `LEA DI, [SI] + 021h`.

If instead, I use:

```
lea di, [si + 4]
```

Then it works as expected.

How do I make the first version work in a similar way to the second?

Comment: If someone can write a better title, please go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your "expected" `4` coming from?  If it's from the contents of `len dw 4h`, then you need a load, like perhaps `add si, [len]`.

**`lea` does *not* access the contents of memory.**

x86 doesn't have a copy-and-add with a memory source, so you have to choose between a "destructive" `add` with a register destination, or `lea` that just does math with registers + assemble-time constants

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can't use `lea` to load the address of si+len. Rather, I would have to use an `add` instruction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `lea di, [si + len]` reduces to `LEA DI, [SI] + 021h` ? Is it because `len` is situated at 021h?

Comment: @Rishav: That's weird syntax, normally you'd write `lea di, [si + 21h]`, but yes if you see that in disassembly it's because `offset len` = 21h.  If you used `[si + len]` as a memory operand for any other instruction, you'd access memory at `len + si`, like C array indexing with `si` as a byte offset.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, that syntax was produced by emu8086 not me.

Comment: @Rishav: emu8086 is weird, and has some strange behaviour.  Like `mov [si], 1` assembles instead of giving an error about ambiguous operand size.  It just picks a default operand size, either byte or word I forget which!